# Make copy of farm and renaming machine names

Tags: 2007, powershell, server-farm

I have a 3 server farm (APP + WFE + DB). Let's call those machines app1, wfe1 and db1.

I made a copy of those machines and then renamed those to app2, wfe2 and db2. Now when I try to open CA on new farm then it goes to http://app1:45358 which obviously doesn't exist.

So is there a way to rename server names and make farm work? Like some powershell command or something to replace all old names with new ones!?

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy machines. What has happened is your 'copy' of the WFE/APP servers have connected to your production SQL Server.

The best course of action is to probably disconnect all SharePoint servers (prod APP/WFE, copied APP/WFE), then reconnect only the production SharePoint servers to the Config db.

At worst, you're looking at building a new farm.

Comment: But I can point new farm to new SQL Server like when we move database from one server to another. But problem is in my case CA is not accessible.

Comment: Here user Kannan mentioned that he successfully did this operation by running products configuration wizard on new farm. I am not sure if it will work or not.

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45158/clone-sharepoint-2010-production-environment-for-test-environment